# python dash keycloak external url/uri

Tags: python, keycloak, plotly-dash

I am on a corporate network where a python app is running with keycloak as ID provider.

Internally it is working flawlessly.

The app is running on an internal server, lets call it internal.local.org.

Now we have a reverse proxy and of course this internal server does not have an external name.

Unfortunately, after logging in to keycloak (even after calling the external adress going via reverse proxy), one is redirected to the internal server internal.local.org.

Does anyone KNOW me how to set the server uri/url so keycloak is also redirecting to the right place for external access?

In keycloak I tried to set the root url and base url, but somehow this does not work.

I suppose, this can be set within the code, but I could not find out how.

Could anyone please give me a hint?

Best regards and thanks in advance,
Otto

Comment: Dash is flask-based and flask has some kind of "SERVER_NAME" Env-Variable to generate external URLs. Maybe you could give this a try.

Comment: Hi @Minato thanks for the hint! I set  DASH_ASSETS_EXTERNAL_PATH and SERVER_NAME for flask in the code. Still after keycloak-auth the system is redirecting to the internal name :-(